Selenide opens https instead of http which I defined explicitly
I am trying to run selenide tests in chrome browser (version 125...). I use IntelliJ to run tests that is why I set up VM options:
Dselenide.baseUrl=http://example.com

But when tests are starting to run the URL becomes https://example.com
I found some information that after chrome version 63 it sets https by default for all URLs, I need to turn this feature off and go to http. Is there any possibility to turn it off? Thanks in advance.

I'm assuming the site is redirecting traffic to https, not the browser. https is more secure... why do you require http?

Because site which I need to test doesn't work by https. It looks like WebDriver adds https, because when I open this website manually in the same (Chrome) browser it opens correctly by http

What's the site?
